# htaccess redirect to enother domain and language

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to write a rewrite rule to redirect from one domain to another.

```
   maindomain.com/en/ -> secounddomain.com/en/
   maindomain.com/en/pagename.html -> secounddomain.com/en/pagename.html
   www.maindomain.com/en/ -> secounddomain.com/en/
   www.maindomain.com/en/pagename.html -> secounddomain.com/en/pagename.html
   secounddomain.com -> secounddomain.com/en/
   www.secounddomain.com -> secounddomain.com/en/
```

and for secure (no back)

```
   secounddomain.com/pl/ -> secounddomain.com/en/
   www.secounddomain.com/pl/ -> secounddomain.com/en/
```

I try to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com/en/$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secounddomain.com/en/$1 [r=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.com/en/$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secounddomain.com/en/$1 [r=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secounddomain.com/pl/$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secounddomain.com/en/$1 [r=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secounddomain.com/pl/$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secounddomain.com/en/$1 [r=301,L]
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this condition is wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com/en/$
```

As `%{HTTP_HOST}` can only match host name hence it can match `maindomain.com` only.

Here is how your .htaccess should look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en(?:/.*|))$ http://secounddomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secounddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^en/)^(.*)$ http://secounddomain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secounddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pl(/.*|)$ http://secounddomain.com/en$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your reply but this doesn't work for me. First, when I put part of your code:

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(pl(?:/.*|))$ https://maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

I got redirect loop error. 
This should redirect from  maindomain.com to  maindomain.com/pl/ ?  
I forgot to say I have to diffrent domain parked to one site. First  maindomain.com go to PL language and secounddomain.com go to EN language .